# forcing page layout on window resize

Tags: html, css

I am designing a webpage and want the layout to remain the same regardless of screen size.  I have looked at POSITION variables like fixed, absolute and relative and explanations but cannot find a clear answer.  I believe it has something to do with nesting divisions.  Can someone give me a more clear answer as to how this work?  Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <title></title>Test
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                width:1300px;
                height:650px;
                color: black;
                position:relative;
                font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
                background: #F4EEFE url(backgrounds/linen2.jpg) center center fixed no-repeat;
            table td { border:0;vertical-align:top; }
#main {margin:0 auto;}
table.master {position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;}
td.david {position:relative;}
td.richard {position:relative;vertical-align:bottom;}
td.forBackground{vertical-align:middle;}
td.middle{height:100px;}
#david{margin-top:10%;}
#richard{margin-bottom:15%;}
img.top{z-index:999;}
#button{z-index:999;display:block;text-decoration:none;bottom:2px;     height:25px;clear:both;float:right; margin-left:47%; position:fixed; border:0px; padding:0px;}
img.davidbio{z-index:999;display:block;text-decoration:none;bottom:15%; height:200px;width:250px;clear:both;float:left; margin-left:11%; position:fixed; border:0px; padding:0px;}
        </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" class="container">
<div id="background-image" class="background-image"></div>
<div id="content">
<center>
  <table class="master" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="20%" class="david"><div id="david"><?php include('david.php'); ?></div>                   </td>
      <td width="55%" class="forBackground">
<div id="main" class="main">
<center>
<table class="background" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="middle"><center><br/><br/><font size="5">Text here</font>   <br/><font size="7">Names here</font></center></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="middle"><center><img src="heart.png" title="" alt="" width="200px" height="150px" /></center></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="middle"><center><font size="5">Date<br/>
        Time<br/>
        Location</font></center></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</center>
</div>
    </td>
    <td width="20%" class="richard"><br/><br/><br/><div id="richard"><?php    include('richard.php'); ?></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</center>
</div>
<input type="button" name="button" id="button" class="button" value="&nbsp;Click Here;" onClick="MyWindow=window.open('input.php','MyWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no')" style="color:#F7D358;background-color:#D33033;border:1px solid;
border-top-right-radius:2em;
border-top-left-radius:2em;
border-bottom-right-radius:2em;
border-bottom-left-radius:2em;"></button>
<img src="davidbio.png" class="davidbio" alt="" title=""/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9hdz2/1/

Comment: don't use percentage widths, use exact pixel values....

Comment: i recommend you the playlist from This Week Startups, very nice introduction to responsive webdesign https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuk4BwEO3C4&list=PLlb3EKZfhFUxKFVMT2lpv2lw498z0fb2l

Comment: I CONSIDER IT IS NOT RESPONSIVE & have same layout on every device

Comment: I have just copied your code to jsfiddle and it seems like your layout already stick to their start position. Can you explain abit more what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the elements to stay in the same position whatever the size of the window, you need wrap all these elements in a tag (for example a `div`) and give it a fixed width.

For example (lets say the container has an id : `#container`), CSS :

```
#container{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto; /*this is to horizontaly center the element 
                     in the window if the window is wider than 960px/*
    }
```

Then you need to use relative or static (default) positioning on the elements inside it and you can use percentages as they are calculated on the parent dimensions which is fixed.

You can also use absolute positioning if you give the `#container` a relative position.

For your aim, I would avoid using fixed positioned elements as their position is calculated according to window and therefore will not follow the `#container` flow.

This explantion is simple so I highly recommend you look through more thorough definitions  espacialy on CSS positioning.

You can find some here :

[CSS positioning overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)